# Can I claim a tax loss for Crypto blockchain shutdown?

Tags: united-states, taxes, cryptocurrency, capital-loss

Short version is that I bought crypto by way of trading BTC/ETH into the coin of discussion and the blockchain of that coin was shutdown. I can't access the balance in my wallet (and never will). Can I claim this as a loss on my taxes?

Additionally, what can I submit as proof to IRS in case of audit as I only have outgoing transactions from Coinbase (which does provide the cost basis).

I've seen mixed messaging on this topic but this article leads me to believe I can:
https://coinledger.io/blog/reporting-stolen-or-lost-cryptocurrency-for-tax-purposes#can-i-claim-a-tax-deduction-on-a-crypto-nft-scam-

---

Longer version:

Several years ago I made BTC transactions totaling slightly over $1000 to purchase a cryptocurrency that has recently "shutdown". This cryptocurrency development team claims that the overall system was not technologically viable (if you will) and they need to restart with a different code base. In order to get the amount of crypto that was previously held, they instruct us to purchase a voucher of equal amount and then they will essentially double what you had.

The crypto's blockchain is dead, their app and servers are defunct. In fact, I can't capture any screenshot of my held balances or get my address because of this. There is no way for me to interact with any previously held crypto from them without first paying them more money and its at this point that I am walking away.

My question is if I can claim this as a capital gains loss. I have seen mixed information online and when entering this amount in a tax software as an "Stock or Investment Sold" (per info from link above) it adds to my refund amount. Also if I can claim this, how can I prove to the IRS if audited any of this information as pretty much all I have are the originating transactions from Coinbase.

Answer (score 4):

Didn't read the whole thing. Generally, you would not get tax advice from random people on the Internet (be it here or on some crypto scam pump site). You'd want to discuss **your** specific situation with **your** licensed tax adviser (EA, or a CPA or Tax Attorney licensed in your State).

What that article does is basically covering all the possible ways things can go wrong, but where you fall in that range is really hard to tell with the information provided.

Is it a case of a scam/theft/manipulation where you were tricked into giving something up? Is it a genuine investment gone wrong? Who knows, and the answer to the tax question depends on it.

For most parts, crypto losses like this are generally scams and not genuine investments, and scam losses are non-deductible. You've essentially been duped into giving your money to someone. You'll need to talk to a licensed tax professional for a more thorough analysis.

Don't forget to report the sale of your BTC/ETH, since that is also a tax event.

Comment: Does the exchange still count as a sale for capital gains purposes if the new crypto was a scam?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica of course

Comment: got a reference?

Comment: Hmmm... [IRC Sec. 61(a)(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/61)? Nothing there that conditions recognition of income based on the intended use of the gains. Sec. 1031 excludes dealing with crypto ([source for prior to TCJA](https://www.dlapiper.com/en-us/insights/publications/2021/07/irs-concludes-section-1031-tax-deferred-like-kind-exchange-treatment), post TCJA Sec. 1031 is only for real estate). So unless it's in a tax-shielded account, yes - it's taxable.

Comment: But if you didn't ever receive money for it, but were just scammed out of the BTC/ETH directly in exchange for something worthless, is there ever a gain to realise?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica of course. What you did with the proceeds is irrelevant.

Comment: [26 U.S. Code § 1001](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1001) - "The amount realized from the sale or other disposition of property shall be the sum of any money received plus the fair market value of the property (other than money) received. In determining the amount realized". In this case no money was received and the FMV of the property was 0 if it was a scam from the beginning.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica that sounds to me like an argument to make in a tax court, which would likely be thrown out as frivolous since the FMV was the price you paid (otherwise why did you pay it?). Otherwise you'd be able to wash away any gain by repurchasing something and claiming it was a scam from the start.

Comment: The crypto purchased was an investment gone wrong in that there was a held balance with some value up until the point that they shut the block chain down due to "technical issues" and are opening up a new blockchain but will not issue any of the balance unless paying them additional money for a "voucher" that would be in the estimated amount of my previous balance. I see this as a new investment not the same, so effectively I could have sold in the past but this abrupt closure of the blockchain occured and now I can't, the investment is nullified to $0 not necessarily stolen.

Comment: Although the exchange which the BTC/ETH was traded to for the purchase of this crypto was owned and operated by the developers of the blockchain/crypto that got shutdown. So while I believe they operated this in good faith, they ultimately earned money from the sale of the crypto in BTC/ETH which is not shut down. I am trying to generalize the situation for the sake of others but I can provide more specific details if it helps.

Comment: @Jeremy That all sounds like a classic scam.

Comment: @nobody It sure felt like a scam to me but this doesn't seem to be planned because I purchased into this crypto as far back as 2018 and it only going defunct late last year.

Comment: @Jeremy so you can't confirm that the value cannot be recovered, which is the condition to write off a loss. This is a scam, and I don't think you can write it off.

Comment: @littleadv the value can't be recovered without spending money and it wouldn't be the same investment it would be a different coin/blockchain. The blockchain my crypto was on was shut down permanently. I'm still confused what records are needed and to what extent the IRS will take personal account or retrospective documentation.

Comment: @Jeremy generally, for tradable securities, you'd sell your worthless position to your broker for $0 and close the position with the loss. I've done it once or twice. In your case, since you cannot sell it to anyone, but you can also not prove that it's a total loss (since there's an avenue for recovery, you just don't want to pursue it), I don't see how you can deduct it.

Comment: @littleadv thank you that is helpful. It sounds like one option may be to pursue the recovery and sell at a loss for 2024 taxes.

Comment: Just a reminder - the advice you get here is worth what you paid for it. For a reliable opinion talk to a licensed tax advisor